# After migration, all featured images using accentued characters in their file names are displayed "blanked"

Tags: images, migration, characters

After migration, all featured images using accentued characters in their file names are displayed "blanked" in the Media Library. Thus, not displayed by respective posts.

I've used the "Better Search and Replace" plugin to check and all URL are corrects. Checking by FTP, all files are present in wp-content/uploads folder.

I've noticed in media library that when a featured image has something like "é, à, ê..." or apostroph in its filename, it displays as a blank broken image.

The website is in french and all 500+ posts are in french too.

Can you help reattach those files please?

Comment: Third party plugins and themes are off topic here at WPSE, so try reaching out to the Better Search and Replace authors for support. As an alternative, you could try migrating the site locally for testing. You can use WP CLI to do the find and replace https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Comment: Thanks for coming back. This is not a plugin issue but a WP database problem I presume. The plugin as been used to check as said. The core issue seems relative to something like base64 or others database stuff I really don't know about.